# Micronaut Picocli Jar executable always exits with 0

Tags: java, bash, shell

I'm running the mycommand.jar and expecting it to fail (there's a System.exit(136) in there).

```
> java -jar mycommand.jar
> EXIT_CODE=$?
> echo $EXIT_CODE
> if [ $EXIT_CODE == 136 ]; then echo success; exit 0; else echo fail; exit 1; fi
```

Yet EXIT_CODE is always 0 for some reason.

EDIT:

The output of my program is:

```
08:24:51.511 [main] WARN  com.aa.utils.Logger - Exiting with error code 136
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.aa.MyCommand.run(MyCommand.java:172)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1939)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2352)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2346)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2311)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.picocli.PicocliRunner.run(PicocliRunner.java:137)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.picocli.PicocliRunner.run(PicocliRunner.java:114)
    at com.aa.MyCommand.main(MyCommand.java:76)
$ EXIT_CODE=$?
$ echo $EXIT_CODE
0
```

And my Java code:

```
        if (mycondition) {
            logger.log(LogLevel.WARN, "Exiting with error code 136");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } else {
            logger.log(LogLevel.WARN, "Exiting with error code 0");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

The output of my program without throwing an exception is:

```
08:24:51.511 [main] WARN  com.aa.utils.Logger - Exiting with error code 136
$ EXIT_CODE=$?
$ echo $EXIT_CODE
0
```

And my Java code in that case is:

```
        if (mycondition) {
            logger.log(LogLevel.WARN, "Exiting with error code 136");
            System.exit(136);
        } else {
            logger.log(LogLevel.WARN, "Exiting with error code 0");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this using a simple program that just does `System.exit(1);` in its main method. Getting 1 as expected. But aren't you confusing 0 and 1? Note that 0 means success, not error.

Comment: It's completely intended. I want to test it fails in a particular case.

Comment: This means that your Java-Program does not do a `Sytem.exit(136)`.

Comment: @user1934428 The exits are in an if-else statement with logging and in the logs it's coming out of the path where the System.exit(136) is

Comment: But note that you are not supposed to return exit code 136 anyway, as this [usually](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) indicates that the program received signal 8. Maybe Java gets confused. Try a more reasonable code, for instance 126. Also - the devil never sleeps! - I would reduce the case to a simple program, which only does the `exit` and nothing else.

Comment: Uhm... that stack trace makes me think that you're spawning something, that something exits with whatever exit code you're telling it to but then the process that spawned it doesn't expect it and throws an exception. At that point whatever exit code you returned from your inner process is gone.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca These are all commands running on a container but yes, it looks like something is happening after my System.exit(n) and before the echo.

Comment: @user1934428 I've switched to 126 and 1 and the behaviour is the exact same.

Comment: Your Backtrace shows files and line numbers. Doesn't this tell you, which  command exactly produces the exception? Have you installed some Exit handlers?

Comment: BTW, I would remove the _bash_ tag from your question, because the `RuntimeException` shows that this is a pure Java problem.

Comment: @user1934428 I'm throwing that exception myself and the issue is the same as when I'm using System.exit(n)

Comment: Now I'm confused: If you throw a RuntimeException, your program is supposed to terminate with exit code 1, isn't it? I suggest that you re-formulate your problem so that we are able to reproduce it.

Comment: a [mre] would eventually help... have you checked [9.1. Exit Code](https://picocli.info/#_exit_code) and subsequent points of picocli.info?

Comment: @user16320675 [here](https://github.com/AbelAlejandro/test2) is a minimal reproducible example where the exit code is always 0 (regardless of how I use System.exit()

Answer (score 1):

My main method was exiting with error code 0, even when my command exited with any other error code.

I had this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PicocliRunner.run(MyCommand.class, args);
    }
```

And I replaced it with this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int exitCode = PicocliRunner.execute(MyCommand.class, args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
```

Thank you Federico klez Culloca